# Can I use classes without include or require statements?

Tags: php, namespaces

i have an index.php:

```
<?php

include_once('X\X.php');

$y= new X\X();
$y->HelloWorld();

?>
```

and say index.php is in folder ROOT, then in ROOT\X I have a file called: X.php:

```
<?php 
namespace X;
     class X{
        public function HelloWorld(){
            echo 'Hello!';
        }
    }
?>
```

My question is, this only works if I have the include_('X\X.php') in my index.php. Is there anyway to say Hello! without including the file?

I am trying to learn namespaces and how they are used actually. 
If I am already including the file, then why bother with namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use namespaces without includes. It's not really recommended, but it can be done.

A given PHP file must be either fully namespaced or not namespaced at all. So if you're going to have namespaces in the file, it must start (ie first line of code) with a namespace declaration.

Once you have that, it is legal (although I'll say again, not recommended) to change the namespace further down the same file (though obviously outside of any class or function, of course).

I would really recommend taking the time to learn about PHP's Autoload mechanism as part of this same learning exercise. It goes together with namespaces very well, and allows you to split your code into separate files for each class (as per best practice recommendations), but without having to manually include each file you need.

Comment: Only Chuck Norris can access classes without including them. Using autoload mechanism means **not** that the file hasn't to be included by the programmer. unlike java where the compiler does the include

Comment: @hek2mgl - yep, you're right (and I like your Chuck Norris bit). But I simplified it for the purposes of the answer, otherwise I would have spent another twenty minutes writing something that was going off topic from the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Learn about [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)() and friends or in better words the Spl Autoload mechanism together with the `include_path` ini directive. Thats cool stuff and will save you many headaches! :)

However, autoloading is not magic. Its just a 'hook' meachnism that the Zend engine calls when a user defined class will be accessed that has not been included before. The parameter to the autoload method is the classname. The method will have to resolve the classname to a file name **and include it** using include or require (*_once).

Assuming that in your case the file X.php would be located in a folder X somewhere in class path you could resolve the name like this:

```
// define your autoloader
function the_autoloader($classname) {
    // $classname  will 'X\X' in the example
    $filename = str_replace('\\', '/', $classname) . '.php';
    require $filename;
}

// register the autoloader
spl_autoload_register('the_autoloader');


// from this point you are free to instantiate every class
// that can be resolved by the_autoloader() without writing 
// an explicit include statement

$y= new X\X();
$y->HelloWorld();
```

As you see, although autoloading eases class usage and includes files 'in background' it is still required to include them. So the answer to the question is : **You'll have to include class files before using them**

Comment: @Koray Tugay Would also like to know what I'm missing. But it was downvoted without the example and the last paragraph

Comment: @KorayTugay Also note my comment below the accepted answer. Just to point you in the right direction. You cannot expect PHP include's anything for you